# C#: Using local object in to another function

Tags: c#

my English isn't good. I have a problem with object specific class.
I creating that object using function (WFA: button_click)

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clas = comboBox1.Text;
        name = textBox1.Text;
        sex = radioButton1.Checked;
        if (nazwa.Length != 0 && nazwa.Length != 0)
        {
            Hero Bohater = new Hero(name, clas, sex);
        }
    }
```

And, when I using another button:

```
private void chodzenie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            if (r % 10 == 0 || r % 10 == 5)
            {
                attack_mode();
            }   
        }
private void attack_mode()
        {
            int wybor = rnd.Next(0, 1);
            if (wybor == 0)
            {
                small_enemy wojo = new small_enemy("Antek");
                while (Bohater.hp >= 0 || wojo.hp >= 0)
                {
                    Bohater.hp -= (wojo.atack - Bohater.defence_p);
                    wojo.hp -= (Bohater.atack_p - wojo.defence);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                big_enemy wojo = new big_enemy("Waldek");
                while (Bohater.hp != 0 || wojo.hp != 0)
                {
                    Bohater.hp -= (wojo.atack - Bohater.defence_p);
                    wojo.hp -= (Bohater.atack_p - wojo.defence);
                }
            }     
        }
```

Visual can't see my object and receive Error

> The name 'Bohater' does not exist in the current context

How to make usable creating object (in function), and uses in global scope?

Ofc all of this is in one file, but another function.
I'm try to get Answer in internet, maybe my searching isn't good.

Comment: This is your reference to read about variable scope in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `Hero bohater` outside of `button1_Click` so that it is defined in the **class** instead of in the **method**.

With your current code, `bohater` is a **local variable** that can only be used inside `button_Click`. If you define it in the class instead, `bohater` becomes a **field** that can be used by any method in the class.

So, at the top of your class, put:

```
private Hero bohater;
```

And inside `button_Click`, put:

```
this.bohater = new Hero(name, clas, sex);
```

You also need to update the `attack_mode` method, like this:

```
while (this.bohater.hp >= 0 || wojo.hp >= 0)
{
    this.bohater.hp -= (wojo.atack - this.bohater.defence_p);
    wojo.hp -= (this.bohater.atack_p - wojo.defence);
}
```

Note that `this` is used to indicate that `bohater` is in class scope. (You don't have to use `this` but it makes the code easier to understand.)

Answer (score 1):

Define it as the property Bohater in the class you are in:

```
public Hero Bohater {get; set;}
```

or define it as a field, if you are just using it internally and temporarily:

```
Hero Bohater;
```

instead of defining it inside an `if` statement inside a button method. 
This will allow other methods within the class to access it, as well as other classes (if desired).  Your definition of the variable only extends to the `if` statement, and does not exist outside of that statement.

Review how the scope of a property/field/variable is determined.  This is just one example of how to solve your problem; there are many others, depending on how you intend to use the "variable".